# Why do bitwise operations differ so much depending on the way i do them in Java

Tags: java, android

Why do first way work correctly (giving me value 2^32):

```
    long negationMask = 0;
    for (long i = 0 ; i < 31 ; i ++)
        negationMask |= 1 << i;

    Log.i("DBG", " Negation mask:  " + Long.toBinaryString(negationMask));

    negationMask <<= 1;
    Log.i("DBG", " Negation mask:  " + Long.toBinaryString(negationMask));

    negationMask |= 1;
    Log.i("DBG", " Negation mask:  " + Long.toBinaryString(negationMask));
```

while the second does not (giving me value of 2^64):

```
    long negationMask = 0;
    for (long i = 0 ; i < 32 ; i ++)
        negationMask |= 1 << i;
    Log.i("DBG", " Negation mask:  " + Long.toBinaryString(negationMask));
```

Is it possible the issue is connected wth optimizations done by compiler? I am using Android Studio 1.5 (Win7)

Comment: You have to operate on long operands : `negationMask |= 1L << i;`

Comment: @Eran Why? The result is within the range of a Java integer.

Comment: @Gravell It is utterly impossible for a calculation that ends by OR-ing 1 to yield a result of 2^32, or any other value that isn't odd. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @EJP (1 << 31) is a negative `int` (`-2147483648`), so when you `|` it with the value of `negationMask` (prior to the last iteration), you get -1. The first snippet gives 2^31-1 (31 least significant 1 bits). I'm assuming the OP expected the second snippet to give 2^32-1 (32 least significant 1 bits).

Comment: @EJP by "value of 2^32 (or 2^64)" I mean 32 (or 64) least significant bits as ones - just like Eran said. Sorry if it was unclear. Eran's solutions works correct.